# How to pass a getter as lambda function?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to pass the getter of a bean as a function. When the function is called the getter should be invoked. Example:

```
public class MyConverter {
    public MyConverter(Function f) {
          this.f = f;
    }

    public void process(DTO dto) {
         // I just want to call the function with the dto, and the DTO::getList should be called
         List<?> list = f.call(dto);
    }
}

public class DTO {
    private List<String> list;
    public List<String> getList() { return list; }
}
```

Is that possible with java 8?

Comment: May I ask why you need to encapsulate the function in the `MyConverter` class? And what are you doing in your `process` method with the result? I'm asking because it sounds like you just need to map a given value to a result (via the provided function) and actually process it. In fact, the `MyConverter` class looks more like a processor than a converter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the constructor of `MyConverter` must take a function, and `process` must take an object, this is probably the best way:

```
class MyConverter<T> {
    //               V takes a thing (in our case a DTO)
    //                       V returns a list of Strings
    private Function<T, List<String>> f;

    public MyConverter(Function<T, List<String>> f) {
          this.f = f;
    }

    public void process(T processable) {
         List<String> list = f.apply(processable);
    }
}

MyConverter<DTO> converter = new MyConverter<>(DTO::getList);

DTO dto = new DTO();
converter.process(dto);
```

Comment: I cannot pass the dto *instance* into the constructor. I must pass the instance (and only the instance) in `process(dto)`. Therefore I have to provide the getter as a function somehow into the constructor

Comment: So what's wrong with the plain old `public void process(Dto dto) { List<String> list = dto.getList(); }` ?

Comment: My goal is that the `Converter` must not know about the implementation of the  `DTO`, and not know how to retrieve the objects data `getList()`. That should be passed from outside, of course otherwise I would not need a converter.

Comment: So `DTO` could be a type variable at `MyConverter`.

Comment: Just a suggestion, as the OP said in the previous comment, “*my goal is that the Converter must not know about the implementation of the DTO*” which makes turning `DTO` into a type variable a natural way a decoupling the code.

Comment: @Holger Yep, I agree that that decouples it nicely.